# postgres compare now (time only) to a time (time only now)

Tags: postgresql, time

I have a column that is `time without time zone` (24 hour time), i.e. 11:30:10 (11:30 AM and 10 seconds).

How would I compare this with now, i.e. if this columns is greater than now (returning true if queried after 11 AM).

Something like:

```
select * from table where time_column < date_part(now(), 'HH:MM:SS');
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

You can use:

```
select * from table where time_column < localtime
```

Note this does the same thing as:

```
select * from table where time_column < to_timestamp(to_char(now(),'HH:MM:SS'),'HH:MM:SS')::time;
```

Comment: `to_timestamp(to_char(now(),'HH:MM:SS'),'HH:MM:SS')::time;` is **way** to complicated. A simple `current_timestamp::time` would achieve the same thing. But using `current_time` or `localtime` is definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong in the current answer.

because `to_timestamp(to_char(now(),'HH:MM:SS'),'HH:MM:SS')::time`

[postgresql document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) says MM is the month range [0-12] not minutes range also in the database time column you should have 24 hour time format so here again you should use.
`HH24`

```
select  to_timestamp(to_char(now(),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')::time;
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing time use current_time built in function. this function returns now time with timezone. if you want specific timezone please set it before.

```
select * from table where time_column < current_time::time;
select * from table where current_time::time between start_time_colum and end_time_column;
```